# how to get redirected from slim Rest API function to codeigniter controller function?

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, redirect, slim

In my slim framework REST API, there is a function say "loadData" with POST method.
This function contains an array named "options".
path of loadData function is:

> c:\xampp\htdocs\cmp_mgmt\app\v1\controllers\xyz.php

I want to call a codeigniter function named "callABC($option)". This function is in file path

> c:\xampp\htdocs\mgmt\application\controllers\Ad.php

.

So what i want is:

```
loadData(Request $request, Response $response, $args)
{
   $options_arr =  $request->getParsedBody(); 
   $call = c:\xampp\htdocs\mgmt\application\controllers\Ad\callABC($options_arr);
  return $response->withJson($call,200);
}
```

So above mentioned code is something i want to do. Please help in redirecting.

Comment: you want something like this

`require('..\..\..\..\mgmt\application\controllers\Ad.php';
loadData(Request $request, Response $response, $args)
{
  $options_arr =  $request->getParsedBody(); 
  $call = callABC($options_arr);
 return $response->withJson($call,200);
}`

Comment: 1) Include it with `require_once __DIR__ . '/../../../../Ad.php';` or 2) Extract that function into a Repo (git, svn) and include the library via composer.

Comment: What if i want to do this with return $response->withRedirect(); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: One can not access any controller that is in other folder and script access is not allowed this way.
So there must be route set in `route.php` then you can access the function using route path.
It can be defined as below :-

```
 $captcha_url = "http://your_api_url/index.php/[route defined in route.php]/"
```

Like for example:- In `route.php` , the route is defined as :-

```
$route['nlpgen/nlpimg/(.+)']='xyz/callABC/$1';
```

then to access controller :-

```
$captcha_url = "http://your_api_url/index.php/nlpgen/nlpimg/"
```

Now you can use `CURL` to access external URL.